# date value after formatting comes back 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, xml, date-formatting

I have this function that formats xml date

```
function frmXMLdate(dteval) {
    (function ($) {
        var Nwdtefrmt = $.format.date(dteval, "MM/dd/yyyy")
        return Nwdtefrmt
    })(jQuery);
}
```

now when i call this function the return value is always 'undefined'
this is how i call it,

```
$('#DobTxt').val(frmXMLdate($(xmldata).find("DOB").text()));
```

any idea why?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to include (function($) part. That is for on document ready and should not be inside a function.

Comment: Thanks for your input